# RCurl SSL Connect Error

Tags: rcurl

I have the following code in one of my applications and was working fine until few days ago.

```
  sdtm<-read.delim(textConnection(getURL("https://evs.nci.nih.gov/ftp1/CDISC/SDTM/SDTM%20Terminology.txt")))
```

Now it is giving **Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : SSL connect error**, I checked forums and I couldn't figure out what is causing the issue. The RCurl package version I'm using is : 1.95-4.8

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you connect to that URL from a web browser etc on the same machine?

Comment: Yes I could connect to the URL from the same machine.